# using mysql instead of sqlite in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure how to find what I'm looking for here, but I've cloned a rails app from someone else and they were using sqlite, how do I switch the project over to mysql? There are no migrations but it has a schema. Thanks.

Comment: Or rather is there a way to make a migration from a schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a migration.  `rake db:setup` (or `rake db:schema:load`)

**EDIT**: this is assuming the schema is a schema.rb file.  If it's an SQL file you'll have to convert that and then just run it using the mysql client.

Answer (score 3):

Have you changed the database.yml?

eg:

```
development: 
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: <db name here>
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: <p/w>
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: yah did all this. It's just annoying to have to run `schema:load` then `db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

hope this will helps you.

If you have some errors in the Database.yml file, you might have to install the mysql gem:

```
gem install mysql
```

Have rake create your database

```
rake db:create     
rake db:schema:load
```

Use YamlDb to reload your data into MySql

```
rake db:load
```

You really should use db:schema:load instead of db:migrate for creating new databases